# How to retrieve a URL's image from the API and display it in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is not a project, I'm simply messing around with a Manga API.

I successfully retrieved the cover's URL from a book, but I'm having a hard time displaying it.
The link is working, but won't display in my view. It shows only a broken image icon.

In this third party website each book has a 6 digit code as identificator, so the api gem works inputing a given code and it will retrieve the information about this specific book.

As an example I just put some random numbers and I'm trying to display this like the title and the cover.

API gem https://github.com/groussel42/nhentai-api/blob/master/lib/nhentai-api.rb

I can successfully retrieve the book's name and display it in the page title. I printed the URL's image just to show that I'm retrieving the link as well.

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'mangas' => 'mangas#show'
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1>Showing <%= @manga.title %></h1>
<%= @manga.cover%>
<%= image_tag @manga.cover %>
```

mangas_controller.rb

```
class MangasController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @manga = Doujinshi.new(250164)
  end
end
```

Here is my view content:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Showing (C94) [OrangeMaru(YD)] Yaou (Fate/Grand Order) [English] [KyuSee]</h1>
https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/1302012/cover.jpg
<img src="https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/1302012/cover.jpg">


</body></html>
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with no knowlededge of the API response or what your `Doujinshi` class contains?

Comment: Also the correct way to define this would be `get 'mangas/:id' => 'mangas#show'` or `resources :mangas, only: [:show]`.

Comment: here the gem https://github.com/groussel42/nhentai-api/blob/master/lib/nhentai-api.rb

Comment: We are not going to dig through that code. If you want help then please provide the information in the question itself. See that `edit` button there? Use it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't imagine that would need to show the api methods, because I said and showed that I'm retrieving correctly the url. The problem is displaying it this url's image.

Comment: The image tag and the URL look good. What exactly is not working? Do you get an error message? An unexpected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't display the image using the link directly because the server doesn't allow it, also known as [hotlinking prevention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking#Server_side).

you have to download the image in your backend and then display it using your own link.

controller:

```
require "open-uri"

File.open('public/cover.jpg', 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.write open("https://t.nhentai.net/galleries/1302012/cover.jpg").read 
end
```

view:

```
<img src="cover.jpg"/>
```

Comment: thanks. There is two things I quite don't get it yet
1. How come the server does not allow, when If I copy and paste the url in browser I can see the image.
2 ..So this is not oficial API if I have to download, right ? Because I if I would make an application using this API i would be just 'stealing' their uploaded books.

Comment: for the 1st question, since you access the image using their domain by pasting the URL directly, it is not a problem. it will be a problem only once you access the image using other domains like your way, or using an iframe. 2nd question: I don't know about the legalities of the API or if the API have the approval from the hentai-site, you have to contact them directly. I also check their Terms and Conditions, but I couldn't find it. You might get in trouble posting other's work, so better consult them.